# golang: CSV file to MS SQL does not work properly without placing fmt.Printf() towards end of for loop

Tags: odbc, go

I am using Go to read CSV file and save the records in a MS SQL database using go-odbc. It works great, but I have an issue where some records (about 10 records) do not get stored. This a random problem, sometimes 3 do not get saved, other times 2, etc. The only time where all the records are saved is when I put `fmt.Printf(" ")` at the end of the for loop. Notice it has to print a blank space it cannot just be `fmt.Printf("")`. I am not sure what am I do not wrong. Any suggestions is appreciated. Also, no errors are produced, the program terminates normally.

I included the code with the related problem, let me know if you need me to post the entire code.

Go version: go1.1 windows/amd64

```
for {
    record, err := c.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {  
        fmt.Printf("Error while reading %s: %s\n", filename, err)
    } else {
        //replace the single quote at the beginning and end of string
        re, err := regexp.Compile("^'|'$")
        params := make([]interface{}, 0, numElements)
        valueHolders := make([]string, 0, numElements)
        tmpFields := make([]string, 0, numElements)
        count := 0

        for i:=1;i<=numElements;i++ {  
            tmp := re.ReplaceAllString(record[i],"")

            //insert only non-empty values
            if len(tmp) > 0 {
                params = params[0:count+1]
                params[count] = tmp

                valueHolders = valueHolders[0:count+1]
                valueHolders[count] = "?"

                tmpFields = tmpFields[0:count+1]
                tmpFields[count] = fieldNames[i-1]

                count++
            }
        }

        query := "insert into [l2test].[dbo]."+tablename+" (" + strings.Join(tmpFields, ",") + ") values (" + strings.Join(valueHolders, ",") + ")"
       stmt, err := dest.Prepare(query)

       if stmt == nil {
           fmt.Printf("Error preparing statment: %s\nQuery: %s\n%v\n\n", err, query, params)
       } else {
          stmt.Execute(params...)
          stmt.Close()
       }
   }

   fmt.Printf(" ")
}
```

Comment: You seem to ignore the error at the end of the first level else. You check for stmt == nil but not for err == nil. Maybe that would tell you something.

Comment: We don't want you to post your entire code. On StackOverflow, reduce your problem to a small piece of code that can be compiled and run to reproduce your problem. It's unreasonable to expect unpaid volunteers to read large amounts of code to solve your problems.

Comment: There are too many possible causes to debug this with your given snippet of code. I don't see you close your connection though so possibly some operations get lost if the connection isn't closed properly after your loop? The addition of the fmt.Printf fix suggests some sort of race condition to me and lack of the Close might be the cause.

Comment: @Jeremy Wall I have made sure I close all the statements, database connection and the CSV file upon completion. The code above is executed in a function to which I pass the database connection and the database connection is closed in main()

Comment: @JimPaek You are right, I do not check for err==nil. Well, in stmt, err:= dest.Prepare(query), if the statement fails to prepare,then err != nil. The problem is that the statment if err!=nil always returns true even if the record is saved successfully. I also tried err==nil, and the statement always evaluates to false. This is perhaps something I need to ask the developers of go-odbc  about.

Comment: @peterSO My apologizes for posting a lengthy code. I certainly do not expect people to read all that code. I will reduce it and try to narrow down the problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: I had this problem about go-odbc before (err always non-nil). I remember fixing it locally, but can't find my fix at the moment.

Comment: I think the problem is in the Success function of odbc.go in the go-odbc driver not working well with Prepare. printf the returned error of the call to Prepare. If it isn't a legitimate error you might edit the driver's error handling in Prepare. Only then you'll be able to check for err != nil || stmt == nil and catch legitimate errors. Then maybe you'll be able to see if anything is wrong with Prepare. Keep in mind it's totally possible err != nil for valid reasons and not the driver's fault (don't know the error, can't tell).

Comment: @JimPaek Thanks for mentioning that. I thought I was the only encountering this problem. I was searching and trying to find people with similar problem, but no luck. I even thought about changing to another odbc package, although I am overall happy with go-odbc. Now you have mentioned go-odbc has this issue, I will work on modifying the local version I have. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drop a few elements at the end, it's usually because you dropped them from the end of the input or didn't write/flush/commit/close them on output. For example, on input you may be ignoring the last slice at EOF. I would write your EOF and error tests differently.

The error handling for your database access needs improvement too. For example, it should check for errors.

Once we find database access errors, add some diagnostic information, such as the `query` and the `record`, to the returned error (`err`).

```
func insertRecord(conn *odbc.Connection, query string, params []interface{}) error {
    stmt, err := conn.Prepare(query)
    defer func() {
        if stmt != nil {
            stmt.Close()
        }
    }()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = stmt.Execute(params...)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

---

```
for {
    record, err := c.Read()
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            fmt.Printf("Error while reading %s: %s\n", filename, err)
            break
        }
        if len(record) == 0 {
            break
        }
    }

    // do things with a record

    query := "insert into [l2test].[dbo]." + tablename +
        " (" + strings.Join(tmpFields, ",") + ")" +
        " values (" + strings.Join(valueHolders, ",") + ")"
    err = insertRecord(dest, query, params)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("%s\n%s\n%v\n%s", err, query, params, strings.Join(record, "||"))
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I attempted the suggestion as you recommended, but still the problem persists. I found out that the records skipped are not necessarily the ones at the end of the file. In fact, the last record gets saved in the database. Also, I made sure I close all odbc statements, close database connection in main() and close the CSV file. I will keep trying and will post any progress I make. Thank you all.

Comment: @user2471801: The next thing to improve is your database access. See my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try that. However, as JimPaek mentioned go-odbc has problem in the Success function that needs to be modified in order to capture the error. Right now go-odbc always returns error non-nil for the Prepare function.

Comment: Your code was ignoring any and all errors! What does the Prepare function return from my code? I've revised the `insertRecord` function to be more robust on failures.

Comment: I tried to check for err not nil and it always evaluates true. But in your code, it actually returns the error. The error returned is "string data , right truncation". The error occurs for few records when I try to insert sex (Female, Male) into a field defined as varchar(50). I tried to increase the field size and change it to nvarchar, I also tried insert just a single character (F or M) but that did not help. While searching for a solution, it is Clear that many people have similar issue with odbc. Thanks for the help, at least I know what is going on now.

Comment: OK, I have been trying to figure the ODBC error. I have all fields data type set to nvarchar(MAX) and I made sure the date I inserted is of the format YYYYMMDD. I ran the program 10 times, 4 out of 10 times all records get inserted, and the remaining 6 times I get "string data , right truncation" on about 2 records (the 2 errored records are not the same in every execution).

Comment: I'm glad to hear my code returned an error! We need more information on the records which cause an error. See my revised answer. I inserted the `err = fmt.Errorf("%s\n%s\n%s", err, query, strings.Join(record, "||"))` statement. What is printed now?

Comment: I added `params` to the list of interesting things to print for an error. See my revised answer.

Comment: ERROR: 22001 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation
INSERT QUERY: insert into [l2test].[dbo].Patients (PersonId,PersonNameFirst,PersonNameLast,PersonNameMiddle,Sex,BirthDate) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)
PARAMS: [20890996 FIRSTNAM LASTNAM M Female 19750303]
ORIGINAL RECORD: '0'||'20890996'||'FIRSTNAM'||'LASTNAM'||'M'||'Female'||'1983/03/03 00:00:00'

Comment: All the fields in the table are nvarchar(MAX) except for the PersonId varchar(50) primary key and BirthDate date

Comment: I have tested the same code on a different machine and it worked fine. No errors. Not sure if I messed up the installation or the configuration on the other machine.

Comment: Just to elaborate on previous message. The error "string data, right truncation" is returned by SQLExecute function used in go-odbc. The machine where the error occurs runs go1.1 and the machine where the same program runs without any issues has go1.0 installed.

Comment: Never mind, after enough testing whether it is go1.0 or go1.1 the error shows up. It is just inconsistent and random.